# Do the cars in Blocky Roads have different specs?

Tags: blocky-roads

The game Blocky Roads has some cars which are locked.  The game has an upgrade mechanism.

Do different but unmodified cars have different handling characteristics, or are the differences only cosmetic?

If a take the first unlocked car an upgrade all the parts to 10/10 will it be the same as the last unlockable car upgraded to 10/10?

Comment: Thanks for fixing the tags. Using the mobile site is hard!

Answer (score 0):

They do have different stats! For example, the tractor will vastly outclass the "Free car for visiting our website" with only half the upgrades of the latter.

Note that it costs more to upgrade the later cars.